# What is the shrubs which loses its brown bark every year?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I recently discovered this shrub in an overgrown section of the garden which is now free to breath. It is about 2.5m high and has 2m in diameter.

The most significant attribute I can associate with it, is its light-brown bark which it throws of every years or so. Foliage is about to appear and it does great red colors in autumn, I can't remember having it seen flowering.

*click for a hi-res version*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a [Crepe Myrtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagerstroemia) to me. There is a nice picture of it here [Is Bark Shedding From A Crepe Myrtle Tree Normal?](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/crepe-myrtle/bark-shedding-crepe-myrtle.htm)

[image]

Comment: I agree, but it seems odd that Patrick B. doesn't remember seeing it bloom if it is a crepe myrtle.

Comment: It was really strongly overgrown with a shrub which flowers at the same time. I don't remember doesn't mean it doesn't flower.